# Iterate over api response Ruby on Rails - Array with Hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, hash

I'm trying to display some data from an api response in my view (Ruby on Rails) and I can't figure it out.

My `html.erb` file looks as follows:

```
<div class="column is-half">
<div class="card">
    <header class="card-header">
        <p class="card-header-title">Contact Personen</p>
    </header>
    <div class="card-content" style="flex: 1;">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </thead>
            <% if @account %>   
                <% @account[:data][0][:contacts].each do |contact| %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= contact[:full_name] || "NVT" %></td>
                            <td><%= contact[:email] || "NVT" %></td>
                        </tr>
                <% end %>
            <% else %>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

`@accounts[:data][0][:contacts]` has the following value:

```
    [{:full_name=>"Kelly example", :emails=>[]},  
    {:full_name=>"Tanja example", :emails=>[{:email=>"tanja@example.nl"}]},  
    {:full_name=>"Mirjam example", :emails=>[{:email=>"mirjam@example.nl"}]},  
    {:full_name=>"Isabelle  example", :emails=>[]},  
    {:full_name=>"Floor  example", :emails=>[]},  
    {:full_name=>"Zosia  example", :emails=>[]},  
    {:full_name=>"Karen example", :emails=>[]},  
    {:full_name=>"Freek  example", :emails=>[]}]
```

It doesn't give any error, but it also doesn't display anything.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @account is empty?

Comment: Looks like a typo in the template: `@account` → `@accounts`.

Comment: ^ aka `@account` will always be `nil`, thus jumping always to the `else`.

Comment: Also, there is no `contact[:email]`. There is `contact[:emails]`.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys, but the variable @account is not nil. I made a typo in my explenation not in my code.